# Cassandra inserts timestamp in UTC time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have json logs with timestamp(UTC TIME) in it. I map keys and values to Cassandra Table keys and Insert the record. However, Cassandra converts the already UTC timestamps to UTC again by subtracting 5 hours from the timestamp. The timezone here is (GMT + 5).

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO myTable (id,time) VAlUES (abc123, 2018-01-12T12:32:31);
```

Now the time is already UTC time and its still inserts a timestamp of 5 hours ago.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: By providing the timezone of your timestamp? Like `2018-01-12T12:32:31Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using cqlsh to insert data, then you can specify default timezone in the `cqlshrc` file using the `timezone` parameter (see [default cqlshrc](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cqlshrc.sample) as example).

If you insert dates programmatically, then you need to convert your time into corresponding type matching to the Cassandra's `timestamp` type (`java.util.Date` for Java, for example).  In your case change could be simple - just append `Z` to timestamp string as pointed by Ralf